# Troubleshooting SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

```
<script runat="server">
  var email = Attribute.GetValue("email");
  var entityKey;
  var emailMatch;
  var contactRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("Contacts", "Email", email);
  if (contactRows != null && contactRows.length > 0) {
    entityKey = Platform.Function.Field(contactRows[0], "EntityKey");
    emailMatch = "True";
  } else {
    emailMatch = "False";
  }
  var checkingLeadsRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("CheckingLeads", "Email", email);
  if (checkingLeadsRows != null && checkingLeadsRows.length > 0) {
    Platform.Function.UpdateData("CheckingLeads", checkingLeadsRows[0]["PrimaryKey"], "EmailMatch", emailMatch);
    Platform.Function.UpdateData("CheckingLeads", checkingLeadsRows[0]["PrimaryKey"], "EntityKey", entityKey);
  }
</script>
```

This script is supposed to use the LookupRows function to search for a match between the "Contacts" and "CheckingLeads" data extensions using the email address. If a match is found in the "Contacts" data extension, it sets the entityKey and emailMatch variables. If a match is found in the "CheckingLeads" data extension, it uses the UpdateData function to update the "EmailMatch" field with the emailMatch value and add the "EntityKey" value to the corresponding field.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have something like "Platform.Function.Field", if you want to access an attribute value, just simply use the `.` or `["field name"]`

And you would need to specify the column name to filter on in the Platform.Function.UpdateData. Read more [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpdateData.html) to put the parameters properly.

Try something like:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load('core', '1.1.1');
var email = Attribute.GetValue("email");
var entityKey;
var emailMatch;
var contactRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("Contacts", "Email", email);

if (contactRows != null && contactRows.length > 0) {
    entityKey = contactRows[0]["EntityKey"];
    emailMatch = "True";
} else {
    emailMatch = "False";
}

var checkingLeadsRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("CheckingLeads", "Email", email);
if (checkingLeadsRows != null && checkingLeadsRows.length > 0) {
    var checkingLeadsRowValue = checkingLeadsRows[0]["PrimaryKey"];
    Platform.Function.UpdateData("CheckingLeads", ["PrimaryKey"], [checkingLeadsRowValue], ["EmailMatch", "EntityKey"], [emailMatch, entityKey]);
}
</script>
```